# Can't databinding combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Sorry for my new question, but I have problem:
I want to add combobox items with databinding, but see NullException ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object."), but I have data in table. This is my code:

```
BesenicaDataSet ds = new BesenicaDataSet();
ds.ReadXml("BesenicaDS.xml");
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Kategorii"].DefaultView;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Kategoriq";
```

UPDATE:

Now, I fixed it with this and can't get exception

```
comboBox1 = new ComboBox(); 
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Kategorii"].DefaultView; 
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Kategoriq"; //second column in table 
comboBox1.ValueMember = "KategoriqID"; //Primary Key column
```

but now ComboBox1.Items.Count == 0 , but I have item in this table. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: What line does it error on? Does the dataset have the data in it?

Comment: How do you know that the "Kategorii" table exists and was named with that name?

Comment: Error is on comboBox1.DataSource .....
And table Kategorii in ds is correct, and ds isn't null

Comment: I rolled the question back to the last edit.  Please don't keep changing the question.  If the *initial* question was answered by a helpful post, mark it as an answer and maybe upvote any other helpful answers, too, and *then* post a new question.  SO likes one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with what you've provided. Set a break-point and see if your DataSet has data in it. If it does, is the DisplayMember spelled correctly, or is the Table? I notice they're very similar, but off by a letter. Check to see if that table exists (set it to Watch or Hover over it). More info would help.

Comment: I Had this table and records in it. And after XMLRead().. in this table Count != 0 .

Answer (score 0):

I bet for whatever reason there is no table called "Kategorii" in the DataSet, which would result in a null reference exception when you try to access `DefaultView`. Check your xml, and under debug conditions check what tables are actually in the DataSet.

It would be helpful if you gave us the stacktrace for this exception and possibly a specimen of your xml file.

One other guess is that `comboBox1` itself is null?

**Bonus points**
I just wanted to check that you're deliberately not setting `ValueMember` on the combobox, or simply omitted it from this example code.

Comment: I have this table, also program crashing in .datasource, so I haven't added ValueMember.

Comment: You're certain you have the table in the DataSet? I suggest you try @steve's example above to check.

Comment: One other guess is that `comboBox1` itself is null?

Comment: Now, I fixed it with this and can't get exception

  comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
  comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Kategorii"].DefaultView;
  comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Kategoriq"; //second column in table
  comboBox1.ValueMember = "KategoriqID"; //Primary Key column
but now ComboBox1.Items.Count == 0 , but I have item in this table. Why?

Comment: @NeilBarnwell i want to ask this : if the defaultview not set explicitly, is it retrieve null or not ??  and may be his xml on the harddisk has values but he changed example connstring and dataset is clearly nul.. can it be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

From the little code given, assuming that the file xml exist and is valid then the only possible cause is

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Kategorii"].DefaultView;
```

Meaning that you don't have a table named "Kategorii" in your DataSet

Try with this

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Kategorii"];
if(dt == null)
    throw new Exception("There is no datatable Kategorii");
else
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I tried this, but again crashed with same error. I had data in this table in XML, and after XMLRead().. in this table Count != 0

Comment: And the line where you get the exception is comboBox1.DataSource = dt?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line select the combobox1 and press Shift+F9 to see its properties. Could you confirm that DisplayMember and ValueMember are set to the columns name of the table?

Comment: Now, I fixed it with this and can't get exception

  comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
  comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Kategorii"].DefaultView;
  comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Kategoriq"; //second column in table
  comboBox1.ValueMember = "KategoriqID"; //Primary Key column
but now ComboBox1.Items.Count == 0 , but I have item in this table. Why?

Comment: So the combovox was null. This explain all. You can't use a reference to an object (combobox1) that's not initialized (new ComboBox()). Without that `new` code you were trying to use a property (DataSource) of a NULL object and this leads to the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: However if you have defined the combobox1 in the designer and here is not visible then you have some other problems that I can't spot without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Can you tell me, why can't add items after this:
comboBox1 = new ComboBox(); comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Kategorii"].DefaultView; comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Kategoriq"; //second column in table comboBox1.ValueMember = "KategoriqID";

Comment: That code creates a new combobox, fill with data, but never display it inside any form. I suppose you have a problem referencing the combobox defined through the designer. The above code when and where is executed? can you show the steps that leads to the above code?

Comment: And just spotted another problem. You said that ComboBox1.Items.Count == 0, but in your previous message you have comboBox1 (with the lower case C). Remember that C# is case sensitive, the two names refer to different objects.

Comment: It's my wrong - it's comboBox1 with first lower case 'c'.
There is all code in Form.Designer for combobox:
in InitializeComponent():
this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 121);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 21);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 13;

and bottom of code:
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;

Comment: The code in your question. I can't see the context in which is called and where is located. If it is inside the same form class where your combobox is declared you should be able to reach the right combobox object.

Comment: There are the link for my app. http://www.gamefront.com/files/21753816/Besenica.zip
This combobox is in Form2. You can open it stripmenu. Please see it and tell me why can't fill data in it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but `file is not available at the moment. retry later`

Comment: I have looked at the source. I can tell you that the `new Combobox1` code is not required (should be removed). It works nicely without it because combobox1 is correctly created in the designer for form2. I have no exception. So here works perfectly. Just the file Besenica.xml seems empty in the source dir and contains 3 items in the bin/debug folder but you don't copy it in the output folder and cannot be the source of the exception.

Comment: the .xml file that I used is in bin-folder, other is not used. So, can you add items from this xml in combobox?

Comment: After my Copy-paste of DataSource-code all worked!
But now, I have other question - how to add new row in dataset?
I used  ds.Dumi.AddDumiRow(PK, Column2, Column3, Column4). But Column4 is int, which is foreign key to other table and I want to put them combobox1.SelectedValue. So, I wrote (BesenicaDataSet.KategoriiRow)comboBox1.SelectedValue on Column4 , but no result... 
Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the following line:

```
comboBox1.DataBind();
```